# LEA vs MOV imm64 for loading address-constant into register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, micro-optimization

I have a constant (64-bit) address that I want to load into a register. This address is located in the code, segment, so it could be addressed relative to RIP. What's the differences between

```
movabs rax, 0x123456789abc
```

and

```
lea rax, [rip+0xFF] // relative offset for 0x123456789abc
```

in terms of execution-speed, and which one is preferable (in a situation where both alternatives could theoretically be used; like in a JIT or when the address can be fixed up at link-time)?

By looking at the disassembly, LEA results in less code, but would it be faster due to this; or potentially slower due to the relative encoded offset?

Comment: I know you said you want it in a register, but if "use rip-relative address directly in a memory operand" was an option then that would really shake up the comparison.

Comment: Related: [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012) - compilers generally prefer RIP-relative LEA because code-size matters more than the fact it can only execute on one port for most use-cases.  Of course, if your address is actually in the low 32 bits of virtual address-space, use 5-byte `mov eax, 0x1234567` (like a Linux non-PIE executable for static data, or like the x32 ABI.  For a JIT, with Linux's `MAP_32BIT` if you want to enable that.)

Comment: @harold Good remark; though I have a few cases where loading to a register is unavoidable (ie. passing a CDATA-reference it a function-call). But I will check to see if I have cases where I could place the RIP-relative addressing directly in the target instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes Might the choice of compilers also have to do with the fact that movabs requires fixup during loading/linking; whiile lea can work without? 
I'm in a normal x64 statically compiled environment, so I cannot guarantee the 32-bit address-range as you described, unfortunately.

Comment: When you say *statically* compiled, do you mean `gcc -static`?  In that case yes, the classic non-PIE code-model in the x86-64 System V ABI does guarantee that static code/data addresses (i.e. `.text`/ `.data` etc.) are in the low 2GiB of virtual address-space so addresses work as signed or unsigned 32-bit immediates. (I think the Windows equivalent is to omit /LARGEADDRESSAWARE, and there is no macOS equivalent).  If you just meant ahead-of-time compiled, then the default on modern Linux systems is to build PIE executables that are mapped to a randomized address outside the low 32 bits.

Comment: Anyway, I mostly mentioned that in an initial comment since your example address, 0x1234567, does fit in 32 bits for `mov eax, 0x1234567`.  If you didn't intend that, edit your example to use a wider address with more of the 48 bits non-zero, like `0x123456789ab`

Comment: @PeterCordes I meant ahead-of time compilation, yes. This is for my own compiler that outputs quasi-JIT code for a bytecode-based language; so I do have some freedom where I load my code.
I did edit to original answer though to make it more clear it's about addresses that don't fit into 32 bits necessarily.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** In a hot loop, the former (`movabs`) is generally faster because it has a higher reciprocal throughput on most modern processors.

---

Indeed, on **Intel** Haswell/Broadwell/Skylake/CoffeeLake/CannonLake/IceLake/TigerLake/RocketLake (too many of those lakes), the `movabs` has a reciprocal throughput of 0.25 while it is 1 for the `lea` (due to the `rip`-relative addressing).

On the quite-recent **Intel AlderLake** hybrid architecture, things are significantly more complex. AlderLake's P-cores (GoldenCove) have a reciprocal throughput of 0.2 for the `movabs` and 1 for the `lea` (mainly due to the `rip`-relative addressing again). AlderLake's E-core (Gracemont) are pretty different: the reciprocal throughput for the `movabs` is 0.33, while it is 0.25 for the `lea`. This means that the best instruction to use is **dependent on where the thread are scheduled**! This is crazy. Even more funny : it looks like Goldmont/Tremont already had fast `lea` with rip-relative addressing while SunnyCove/WillowCove. This is because the architecture for the P-core and E-core are designed for different purpose (AFAIK Mon-like architectures was designed for low-power processors while Cove-like ones was designed for desktop processors). Not to mention Intel certainly hadn't initially planned to mix the two kind of architectures in the same chip.

On **AMD** Zen1/Zen2, it is 0.25 for the `movabs` and 0.5 for `lea`, so the former is also better. On AMD Zen3/Zen4, both have a reciprocal throughput of 0.25 so they are equally fast on this architecture.

That being said, the former take more **space** and it is likely slower to **decode** than the later so the later might be better outsize a hot loop. Indeed, instructions are decoded to µops once and then put in a cache for relatively-short loops, but the decoding is typically a bottleneck for large code executed once (no hot loop or very large one and a code that may need to be fetched from the RAM or the L3).

Comment: In a loop of mostly `lea reg, [rip+rel32]` instructions, yeah it could be a bottleneck, but most loops contain a mix of instructions!  And if you're repeatedly using RIP-relative LEA, probably that's setup for a function call, so you're not going to run better than 1/clock anyway.  If not, just hoist the LEA out of the loop and use the register value.

Answer (score 3):

Compilers prefer RIP-relative LEA because code-size matters more for most use-cases than the fact it can only execute on one port on Intel CPUs (https://uops.info/ and Jérôme Richard's answer).  Also because it's position-independent, unlike `movabs`, so we should at least consider both options.  (Runtime fixup of a 64-bit absolute addresses *is* supported in PIE executables on Linux, but it means the dynamic linker has to remap the page writeable and then back to executable.  **"Text relocations" are generally something to avoid**, and `ld` will warn about it.  So that's a big negative against `movabs` for non-JIT use-cases in modern executables on all mainstream OSes.)

`movabs` on Sandybridge-family with an immediate that actually has more than 32 significant bits takes extra time to fetch from the uop cache, according to Agner Fog's testing, and has some limits on packing as tightly into the uop cache since it needs to borrow space. (https://agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf#page=125 - in the Sandybridge section: this may have changed some in later CPUs).  The 10-byte x86 machine-code size cost still generally makes it something to avoid, even without any uop-cache penalties.

If you need to get an address into a register more than once per clock, copy from another register that you set up outside the loop, or load from memory (with a RIP-relative addressing mode or from stack space.)

In a loop making a function call, that will be a bigger bottleneck than 1/clock anyway.

---

Of course, if your address is actually in the low 32 bits of virtual address-space, use 5-byte `mov eax, 0x1234567` (like a Linux non-PIE executable for static data, or like the x32 ABI.  For a JIT, with Linux's `MAP_32BIT` if you want to enable that.)

Related: [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register) covers the details of the choices, but without discussing the LEA throughput tradeoff.